# Having problems with find_element_by_class_name

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a `Selenium` script and ran into a snag that I am hoping someone can help me with. I have this element on the page:

```
<li class="text-right">
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default js-ajax-api-track-form-submit"­ data-tracking-token="$lookup;­table=login;event=site">
</li>
```

I was able to find the element by using `find_element_by_class_name` (I think) but when I call `.click()` on it, nothing seems to happen. Is this the correct way to interact with this type of element? I have the script checked in [here](https://github.com/Naughtron/naughton_selenium/blob/master/selenium_login_example.py)­ if anyone has time to take a look. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're clicking in the center of the `<li>`.  If you want to click the login button, try this instead:

```
username_box.send_keys('usernamegoeshere')
password_box.send_keys('userpasswordgoeshere')

# find the login submit button 
log_in_submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-right>input')
log_in_submit.click()
```